# Is it true that when $n \geq 5$ there is a surjective homomorphism from the symmetric group $S_n$ to $S_{n-1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Is it true that when $n \geq 5$ there is a surjective homomorphism from the symmetric group $S_n$ to $S_{n-1}$? How come this is so? Does it have to deal with the subgroup $A_n$ being simple?

Comment: The kernel of a surjective homomorphism from $S_5$ to $S_4$ would have to be of order $5$, but $S_5$ does not have a normal subgroup of order $5$,

Comment: ah so is it when n $\leq$ 4 we will have a surjective homomorphism between $S_n$ and $S_{n-1}$